# Devise routing error for edit_user_registration and users/edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I am getting this error whenever I go to /users/edit when signed in:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

Why is the users/edit trying to look for the show action in the users controller?

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users do
    get 'users', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user_root # Rails 3
  end

  resources :users, :only => [:index, :show]

  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end

  root :to => 'home#index'
```

rake routes:

```
 user_root                GET    /users(.:format)               users#show
 new_user_session         GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
 user_session             POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
 destroy_user_session     DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
 user_password            POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
 new_user_password        GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
 edit_user_password       GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                          PUT    /users/password(.:forma        devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
 user_registration        POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
 new_user_registration    GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
 edit_user_registration   GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                          PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
 users                    GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
 user                     GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
 root                     /                                     home#index
 root                     /                                     home#index
```

Comment: This because you have `GET /users/:id(.:format)` and `GET /users/edit(.:format)`. So maybe devise don't know `:id` and `edit` are different, it just think they are same parameter for `/users/` path. I had this problem before, my solution is make a other route for users/show: `match 'profiles/:id', to: 'users#show', as: :profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird!

So I stepped through all my last changes and found out the issue was with this line of code located in views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to current_user.email, user_path  %>
```

For some reason when their is a link to user_path in the layout file, the routing in the site gets all messed up.

To fix it I just changed `user_path` to `current_user` so my new link looks like this:

```
<%= link_to current_user.email, current_user  %>
```

What is really weird is that when you use a link to `user_path` anywhere but the layout/application.html.erb file the routing works fine.